# How to unzip a few directories with zip files which also contain sub-directories with zip files?

Tags: find, directory, filenames, zip, xml

I've **4 folder** & inside each of them, there're a **folder XML** that contain *zip files* & some *folders with zip files*

*All of the zip files contains files in XML format*

```
/A/XML/:
  BDL_DCR_20170216.zip
  BDL_BPR_20170218.zip
  .
  .
/A/XML/zipped:
  BDL_CPR_20170221.zip
  BDL_BPR_20170220.zip
  .
  .

/B/XML/:
  BDL_DCR_20170216.zip
  BDL_BPR_20170218.zip
  .
  .
/B/XML/20170221/:
  BDL_DCR_20170216.zip
  BDL_BPR_20170218.zip
  .
  .
/B/XML/zipped/:      BDL_DCR_20170216.zip
  BDL_BPR_20170218.zip
  .
  .
```

**the rest with similar pattern**

```
`/C/XML-20170221, *.zip`

`/D/XML-20170221, 20170220, 20170219`
```

I wanted to unzip all of it & save it to some directory **X**

I tried to unzip one of it by:

```
find /home/A/XML -type f -name "*.zip" | unzip /home/A/XML/*
```

& got the following error:

```
Archive:  /home/A/BDL_XM_20170221.zip
caution: filename not matched:  /home/A/XML/ZIPPED
caution: filename not matched:  /home/A/XML/20170221.zip
```

I'm thinking maybe there's something wrong with `unzip /home/A/XML/*` cause in simple case is unzip `/home/A/XML/*.zip`

Can anyone suggest how can I *unzip all of the folders one shot*? How can I **unzip** all the *zip files* & the *folders with zip files*?

Thanks a lot, appreciate your help :)

Comment: I don't understand your folder structure.  Can you provide the actual output from `ls -l` in the relevant directories (truncate it, if there are too many lines).

Comment: @EightBitTony Thanks for raising the question, I've edited my questions. Pls have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested but try

`find /home/A/XML -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip '{}' -d /target/path \;`

Someone will be along in a bit to remind me to use `xargs` instead.

Comment: Quite the opposite: the basic rule of xargs is, use `-exec` instead.

Comment: The code is working fine :) Thanks alot. I saw some people used `-execdir` instead, what is the different?

Comment: `-execdir` changes the working directory to the one in which the file is located before executing the command, `-exec` doesn't.  The implications and uses might be worth a full answer rather than a comment - in which case, feel free to ask a new full question asking about the differences with your specific example above.

Comment: @Gilles thanks, I went a did a bit more reading, I was sure the advice a few years ago was `xargs` by preference, but looks like I was mistaken!